# How to determine number of intervals in an interval_map without iteration?

Tags: c++, boost, intervals

I can determine how many intervals are in an interval_map by iterating over the intervals, but is there a more direct method for getting the number of intervals in an interval map? The size() method of boost::icl::interval_map doesn't seem to return a meaningful value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how many steps an iteration would take use [`boost::icl::interval_map::iterative_size()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost/icl/interval_base_map.html#id650044-bb). It's defined in `boost::icl::interval_base_map` and inherited by `interval_map`.